# Can I name a tuple (define a structure?) in Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, syntax, types

It does not look very good for me to always repeat a line-long tuple definition every time I need it. Can I just name it and use as a type name? Would be nice to name its fields also instead of using ._1, ._2 etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can simply use a type alias:

```
type KeyValue = (Int, String)
```

And, of course, Scala is an object-oriented language, so regarding your second about how to specialize a tuple, the magic word is *inheritance*:

```
case class KeyValue(key: Int, value: String) extends (Int, String)(key, value)
```

That's it. The class doesn't even need a body.

```
val kvp = KeyValue(42, "Hello")
kvp._1    // => res0: Int    = 42
kvp.value // => res1: String = "Hello"
```

Note, however, that inheriting from case classes (which `Tuple2` is), is deprecated and may be disallowed in the future. Here's the compiler warning you get for the above class definition:

> warning: case class `class KV` has case class ancestor `class Tuple2`.  This has been deprecated for unduly complicating both usage and implementation.  You should instead use extractors for pattern matching on non-leaf nodes.

Answer (score 18):

Type alias is fine for naming your Tuple, but try using a case class instead. You will be able to use named parameters

Example with tuple:

```
def foo(a : Int) : (Int, String) = {
  (a,"bar")
}
val res = foo(1)
val size = res._1
val name= res._2
```

With a case class:

```
case class Result( size : Int , name : String )
def foo(a : Int) : Result = {
  Result(a,"bar")
}
val res = foo(1)
val size = res.size
val name= res.name
```

Comment: Don't tuples work faster than case classes? The task is complex processing of large amounts of simple data, a kind of number-crunching.

Comment: @Ivan: Tuples *are* case classes, are they not?

Comment: Tuples are indeed case classes!

Comment: Is there a way to add elements to res in loop?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that creates a type alias and a factory object.

```
scala> type T = (Int, String)                          
defined type alias T

scala> object T { def apply(i: Int, s: String): T = (i, s) }
defined module T

scala> new T(1, "a")
res0: (Int, String) = (1,a)

scala> T(1, "a")
res1: (Int, String) = (1,a)
```

However as others have mentioned, you probably should just create a case class.

Answer (score 1):

Although as others have said, explicit (case) classes are best in the general sense.

However for localized scenarios what you can do is to use the [tuple extractor](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) to improve code readability:

```
val (first, second) = incrementPair(3, 4)
println(s"$first ... $second")
```

Given a method returning a tuple:

```
def incrementPair(pair: (Int, Int)) : (Int, Int) = {
  val (first, second) = pair
  (first + 1, second + 1)
}
```